# simple reading from text file

Tags: java, io

I am trying to read some input from a text file, and seem to getting some weird results. I have a text file that has (I made sure there were no extra white spaces) :

```
acdec
```

I read in the text file as a string, then convert it to an array. I then compare the first element of both arrays which have equal values, and should execute the if statement but it executes the else. 
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("tester.txt"));
        String one = sc.next();
        String a[] = one.split("");
        String[] b = { "a", "c", "d", "e", "c" };

        if (a[0] == b[0]) {
            System.out.println("Same");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Same");
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do a simple Google search before asking questions like this.

Comment: Your code would make more sense if you create array oh char and not array of string of length 1! Anyway sparky provided the right fix

Comment: When executing the code `System.out.println(b[0])` IN the if statement prints out nothing, but when executed before the if statement, prints "a". I can only assume the if statement isn't even running, so there's your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in that for string comparison, you have to use the following:

```
if (a[0].equals(b[0]) {
    ....
}
```

When you use `==`, you are comparing the *reference* which the values are pointing to whereas `.equals()` is comparing the actual *value*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to deal with character array instead of an array of Strings to achieve your test results. Note that characters are represented within single quotes instead of double.

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Users/908752/tester.txt"));
        String one = sc.next();
        char a[] = one.toCharArray();
        char[] b = { 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c' };

        if (a[0] == b[0]) {
            System.out.println("Same");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Same");
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```